Output Noise of MOSFET with parallel current source
How can I calculate output noise voltage of the given circuit?
Noise contribution of the M1 to output noise current: $$4kT\delta g_{m1}$$
Noise contribution of the RG to output noise current: $$4kTR_G[g_{m1}(r_{o1}||g_{m2}g_{m3})]^2$$
What will be the noise contribution of M2 and M3?
I know paralleling MOSFETs will decrease the noise contribution but equation below seems logical too.
Noise contribution of the M2+M3 to output noise voltage: $$4kT\delta g_{m2} + 4kT\delta g_{m3}$$
Hence,
$$i^2_{out}=4kT\delta g_{m1}+4kT\delta g_{m2} + 4kT\delta g_{m3}+4kTR_G(g_{m1})^2$$
Is this calculation true?

